sway exec doesn't do the same as the same command in cli
I have written an python program to handle sending notifications to dunst with notify-send. i am aware that there are better alternatives, but i wanted to make it on my own.
This is my program located in /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst
import os
import json
import time
import sys

global name, standard_ttl, standard_ttl_s
data_path = 'data.json'
name = 'Volume Control'
standard_ttl = 1000
standard_ttl_s = standard_ttl / 1000

def get_timestanp():
    return int(round(time.time(), 0))

def get_volume_master():
    command = 'awk -F"[][]" \'/Left:/ { print $2 }\' <(amixer sget Master)'
    return os.popen(f'{command}').read().strip()

def get_if_muted():
    command = "amixer get Master | grep 'Left:' | awk -F'[][]' '{print $4}'"
    returnstate =  os.popen(command).read().strip()
    if returnstate == "off":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def data_exists(data_path):
    if not os.path.exists(data_path):
        data = {"message" : {"last_called" : get_timestanp(), "last_message_id" : 0, "volume" : get_volume_master()},
                "mute" : {"state" : get_if_muted()}}
        save_data(data)

def save_data(data):
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

def load_data(data_path):
    data_exists(data_path)
    with open(data_path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

def cli_command(command):
    return os.popen(f'{command}').read().strip()

def notify(message="No message provided.", id=0, ttl=standard_ttl):
    return_data = os.popen(f'notify-send -t {ttl} -r {id} -p "{name}" "{message}"').read().strip()
    print(return_data)
    return return_data

def main():
    args = sys.argv
    data = load_data(data_path)
    if len(args) == 1:
       notify("Error: No arguments provided. Please provide an argument.")
       return
    
    # check if the argument is valid
    if not (args[1] == "raise" or args[1] == "lower" or args[1] == "mute"):
        notify("Error: Invalid argument provided. Please provide a valid argument.")
        return
    
    # do if argument raise
    if args[1] == "raise":
        cli_command(f'amixer set Master {args[2]}+')

        if get_timestanp() - data['message']['last_called'] <= standard_ttl_s:
            return_data = notify(f'Volume raised from {data["message"]["volume"]} to {get_volume_master()}', data['message']['last_message_id'])
        else:
            return_data = notify(f'Volume raised from {data["message"]["volume"]} to {get_volume_master()}')
        # update the data
        data['message']['volume'] = get_volume_master()
        data['message']['last_message_id'] = return_data.strip() 
        data['message']['last_called'] = get_timestanp()
        save_data(data)

    # do if argument lower
    elif args[1] == "lower":
        cli_command(f'amixer set Master {args[2]}-')

        if get_timestanp() - data['message']['last_called'] <= standard_ttl_s:
            return_data = notify(f'Volume lowered from {data["message"]["volume"]} to {get_volume_master()}', data['message']['last_message_id'])
        else:
            return_data = notify(f'Volume lowered from {data["message"]["volume"]} to {get_volume_master()}')
        # update the data
        data['message']['volume'] = get_volume_master()
        data['message']['last_message_id'] = return_data.strip()
        data['message']['last_called'] = get_timestanp()
        save_data(data)

    # do if argument mute
    elif args[1] == "mute":
        if data['mute']['state']:
            cli_command('amixer set Master unmute')
            
            if (get_timestanp() - data['message']['last_called'] <= standard_ttl_s):
                return_data = notify('Unmuted', data['message']['last_message_id'])
            else:
                return_data = notify('Unmuted')

            # update the data
            data['message']['last_message_id'] = return_data.strip()
            data['mute']['state'] = False
            data['message']['last_called'] = get_timestanp()
            save_data(data)
        elif not data['mute']['state']:
            cli_command('amixer set Master mute')
            
            if (get_timestanp() - data['message']['last_called'] <= standard_ttl_s):
                return_data = notify('Muted', data['message']['last_message_id'])
            else:
                return_data = notify('Muted')

            # update the data
            data['message']['last_message_id'] = return_data.strip()
            data['mute']['state'] = True
            data['message']['last_called'] = get_timestanp()
            save_data(data)
        else:
            notify("Error: Something went wrong.")

main()

When I run the program from the command line, for example:
/home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/bin/python /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/main.py raise 10%
a notification pops up saying what it should say.
But if I try to trigger it with the keybind set in home/theo/.config/sway/config which is:
    # sound
    # amixer set Master 10%+
    bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec "/home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/bin/python /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/main.py raise 10%"
    # amixer set Master 10%-
    bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec "/home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/bin/python /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/main.py lower 10%"
    # amixer set Master mute/unmute 
    bindsym XF86AudioMute exec "/home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/bin/python /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-dunst/main.py mute"

it just gets to the part of the python script where the command to the cli to for example with raise to raise the volume is sent
    # do if argument raise
    if args[1] == "raise":
        cli_command(f'amixer set Master {args[2]}+')

after this it seems to have an error or to just exit the program. the last adjustment is still made though.
what disturbs me is that the same command executed from me and from sway seem to do different things and i don't understand why.
For trying to solve it I tried logging what the program from sway executed does, and it sends notifications up until the point where cli_command(f'amixer set Master {args[2]}+') is executed. after that the program seems to crash. Unfortunately I didn't find anything about it online.

"to have an error or to just exit the program" - do you sometimes seen an error (and if so, what error) and sometimes it just exits? Or are you saying you don't know what happens, but you don't see an error message at all? Have you tried pausing the calling program instead of allowing it to terminate, to see if that changes the behaviour?

I don't see an error, because i cant see the output that it has when sway runs it. I just think it exits or has an error because i dont think theres another reason why it should just stop in the middle of the script. If i run it in the terminal it runs perfectly fine.

The error was just, that sway was  running the command in /home/theo and the data.json file was saved in /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-control. By setting the commands in the swayconfig to: bindsym examplekey exec "cd /home/theo/Repos/volumebar-control && bin/python main.py the script gets executed in the correct directory and the data.json file is found.
